# Show that $\sum_{n=1} ^{\infty} \frac {1}{(x+n)^2} \leq \frac{2}{x} $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality

> Show that $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1} ^{\infty} \frac {1}{(x+n)^2} \leq \frac{2}{x} $

For any real number x $\geq 1$, I want to show the above

Very rusty on my analysis, I think I need to do a comparison test to show the series converges, but then not sure what after that to get the inequality.

Comment: $\Sigma\le \int_x^\infty\frac 1 {y^2}\,dy=\frac 1 x$.

Comment: The only constraints on $x$ in the question are real and $\geq 1$, why do we need an upper limit?

Comment: $$\forall x>0,\qquad\sum_{n=1} ^{\infty} \frac {1}{(x+n)^2}\leqslant\sum_{n=1} ^{\infty} \frac {1}{(x+n-1)(x+n)}=\sum_{n=1} ^{\infty} \frac {1}{x+n-1}-\frac1{x+n}=\frac1x$$ Refining this slightly: $$\sum_{n=1} ^{\infty} \frac {1}{(x+n)^2}\leqslant\sum_{n=1} ^{\infty} \frac {1}{(x+n-1/2)(x+n+1/2)}=\frac1{x+1/2}$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $n\ge 1$, for $x> 0$ we have $$\frac{1}{(x+n)^2}\le\frac{1}{(x+t)^2}\le\frac{1}{(x+n-1)^2}\qquad\text{for }n-1\le t\le n$$
Then
\begin{align}
\int_{n-1}^{n}\frac{1}{(x+n)^2}\,dt&\le \int_{n-1}^{n}\frac{1}{(x+t)^2}\,dt\\[6pt]
\frac{1}{(x+n)^2}&\le\frac{1}{x+n-1}-\frac{1}{x+n}\\[6pt]
\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{(x+n)^2}&\le\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x+N}
\end{align}
Then, as $N\to\infty$ we get 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(x+n)^2}\le\frac{1}{x}$$

Answer (score 3):

Use for $n\geq 1$
$$\frac{1}{(n+x)^2}\leq \frac{1}{(x+n-1)(x+n)}=\frac{1}{x+n-1}-\frac{1}{x+n}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Too long for a comment:**

> As an aside, the series evaluates to $S(x)=\psi_1(x)-\dfrac1{x^2}:$ see [trigamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigamma_function). For $x=0$, we [have](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem) $S(0)=\dfrac{\pi^2}6:$ see [Riemann $\zeta$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) for more information. And if the iterator would have started at $-\infty$ instead of $1$, its value would have been $\bigg[\dfrac\pi{\sin(\pi x)}\bigg]^2$, which can be shown by twice differentiating the natural logarithm of [Euler's reflection formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula) for the [$\Gamma$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).

---

$($When I studied analysis in college, no one told us the “story” or the meaning behind the various series presented during class hours, or mentioned in the exercise section. I hope that you will find this information interesting, and that it will enrich your learning experience$)$.